# Express the integral of $|f|^{2}$ for a holomorphic function $f$ on a disc using its power series coefficients.

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

This post is related to this one: [How to bound the $L^\infty$ norm of a holomorphic function by its $L^2$ norm on a larger domain?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926277/how-to-bound-the-l-infty-norm-of-a-holomorphic-function-by-its-l2-norm-on).

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on $D_{R}(z_{0})$, then we know that it can be expressed as a power series $$f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^{n},$$ where the power series converges in $D_{R}(z_{0})$, and converges absolutely and uniformly in $\overline{D_{r}(z_{0})}$ for all $0<r<R$.

The accpected answer of the above referred post seems suggesting that we can express the integral $$\int_{0}^{R}\int_{0}^{2\pi}f(z_{0}+re^{i\theta})\overline{f(z_{0}+re^{i\theta})}rdrd\theta$$ in terms of the coefficients of power series.

---

This is a pretty interesting fact, and I tried to prove it. At some stage I believe we need to interchange the summation and double integral, but I got stuck even at the beginning.  So $$f(z):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^{n}\ \ \text{and}\ \ \overline{f(z)}:=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{a_{n}}\overline{(z-z_{0})}^{n},$$ this gives us
\begin{align*}
f(z)\overline{f(z)}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^{n}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{a_{n}}\overline{(z-z_{0})}^{n}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^{2}|z-z_{0}|^{2n}\sum_{k\neq m}a_{k}\overline{a}_{m}(z-z_{0})^{k}(\overline{z}-\overline{z}_{0})^{m}.
\end{align*}

Now we replace $z=z_{0}+re^{i\theta}$. The first summation then turned into $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_{n}|^{2}r^{2}$ and the second summation then turned into $$\sum_{k\neq m}a_{k}\overline{a}_{m}r^{k+m}e^{ik\theta-im\theta}.$$ What should I do to deal with the second sum? I am not sure what I should do now..

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int_0^{2\pi} (\sum_n a_n r^n e^{it n})(\sum_m \overline{a_m} r^m e^{-it m})dt$$
$$ = \sum_n\sum_m a_n \overline{a_m} r^{n+m} \int_0^{2\pi} e^{it (n-m)}dt =\sum_n a_n \overline{a_n} r^{2n} 2 \pi$$
This calculation is standard for (absolutely convergent) Fourier series

Comment: Oh right. I forgot the orthogonality of complex exponential function. Thanks!

Comment: It is the same when searching the residue of $e^z e^{1/z}$ at $0$